# sorting of arraylist in kotlin for recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, sorting, android-recyclerview

I am giving app name, icon, package name, hour, mint, sec to an array my major problem is I want to sort this array according to most used app

```
    appInfoList.add(AppInfo(appName, appIcon, packageName, hour, mint, sec))

    appInfoList.sortBy { it.mint }
```

it didn't sort an array

Answer (score 0):

Is your `appInfoList` a `MutableList`? It needs to be a mutable list to sort the array. See [this guide here](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/sort#2-sortby) on using Kotlin's `sortBy` function.

You can cast your list to a mutable list before sorting, like this:

```
val mutableAppInfoList = appInfoList.toMutableList()
mutableAppInfoList.sortBy { it.mint }
```

The `mutableAppInfoList` variable should contain the sorted list after calling `sortBy`.

Comment: but how we follow the criteria in that which app is used more by hour  mint or sec goes on top

Comment: that doesnot work in my case

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You want to sort by most used time? If so, maybe create a single time variable for AppInfo that is created by adding together the hour, minute and seconds. Then you can use sortBy with the time variable.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code this way

```
appInfoList
        .sortByDescending { it.hour * 3600 + it.min * 60 + it.sec }
```

The first element in the list will be the most used one.